# Notation in statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, notation

I'm reading an old document and I came across a notation I'm unsure of,

assumed to be statistically and independent and uniformly distributed, viz,

$p(\phi)\mathrm{d}\phi = \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{2\pi}$

and

follows a Marshall-Palmer distribution

$N(D)\mathrm{d}D = \mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda D}\mathrm{d}(D\Lambda)$

E.g. the first equation states a uniform distribution given by $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. However, I don't understand the $\mathrm{d}\phi$ on both sides of the equation (I assume It's not a differential and if it is then what for?). The same goes for the second equation. Also, I assume that $p(\phi)$ is the notation for "the probability of a certain $\phi$, but in the second distribution, it's noted $N$? Would anyone give me an explanation of how it should be interpreted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could show the relevant context in the document you are reading.  However, even without this, it is pretty clear that the $d \phi$ term is a differential, and presumably $\phi$ is the angle-of-rotation for some measurement so that $\phi \sim \text{U}(0, 2 \pi)$.

In [Marshall and Palmer (1948)](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469%281948%29005%3C0165%3ATDORWS%3E2.0.CO%3B2) they examine data on raindrop size on dyed filter paper.  They take $D$ to be the spherical diameter of raindrops and they find that the empirical data is consistent with an exponential distribution $D \sim \text{Exp}(\Lambda)$ with rate parameter $\Lambda > 0$.  The density function  for this random variable is $N(D) = \Lambda \exp (- \Lambda D)$.  Multiplying both sides by the differential $dD$ and recognising that $\Lambda dD = d(D \Lambda)$  you then have:

$$N(D) dD = \exp (- \Lambda D) d(D \Lambda).$$

It is misleading to refer to this as a "Marshall-Palmer distribution"; it is really just an exponential distribution.  Marshall and Palmer use some notation that would be considered non-standard in statistical work today, but they are essentially doing an analysis comparing raindrop size to an exponential distribution.

---

Marshall, J.S. and Palmer, W.M. (1948) [The distribution of raindrops with size](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469%281948%29005%3C0165%3ATDORWS%3E2.0.CO%3B2). *Journal of Meteorology* **5**, pp. 165-166.